# How to find the $R [X]$-linear combination by using the Euclidean algorithm

Tags: linear-algebra, euclidean-algorithm

I just learned the Euclidean division, I know the definition, but when doing the exercise, I have no idea what should I begin with.

Here is a question:

Let $f :=X^5+3X^4−2X^3−10X^2−2X+4 ∈ Q[X]$ and $g:=X^4+4X^3+6X^2+5X+2 ∈ Q[X]$ . Using the Euclidean algorithm, compute the greatest common divisor $(\gcd)\,d $ of $ f $ and $ g $ and write down the correspondent $ R[X]$-linear combination:
$d(X) = a(X)f(X) + b(X)g(X)$.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: begin by computing $f-Xg$

Comment: could you please make an example?

Comment: Do you know how to do long division of polynomials? That's what you need to do here

Comment: Sure, I will try that, thank you

Comment: note that  $f(X)=(1+X) (2+X) \left(2-4 X+X^3\right)$ and $g(X)=(1+X) (2+X) \left(1+X+X^2\right)$